# How do I determine if my system is Windows 10 using the command line?

Tags: command-line, windows-10

I'm working with InstallAnywhere, an old program for creating installers. I would like to install a particular file, only in case of Windows XP and Windows Vista.

Due to InstallAnywhere limitations, this is not possible. I can only decide to delete the file once it has already been installed, based on a rule.

Within that rule, I can check for the platform on which I'm running, which gives me the possibility to check for Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7, etc. but not for Windows 10. I can't say "Perform this action when the system is not XP or Vista", so I need to say "Perform this action on all those platforms, which are not XP or Vista".

However, I can launch command-line commands and catch the result, so here's my question: is there a command which I can use for determining if I'm working on a Windows 10 system?

Comment: `winver` will pop up the About Windows dialog if typed in cmd or Start. Would that work? Alternatively - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792740/how-to-tell-what-version-of-windows-and-or-cmd-exe-a-batch-file-is-running-on

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm looking for a command-line command which gives an answer in the command-line, I can't use the information in a batch-type way when a messagebox pops up.

Comment: Check for cmd.exe version, it's the easiest and supported at least since XP. There is a question about it.

Comment: I've just tried it on my Windows 7 system: `cmd --version` give as a result `Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]`, so the relation between `cmd` version and Windows version seems not that straightforward, what can I expect on Windows 10?

Comment: google cmd versions, each os has different version number, you can check for that and you don't need any unnecessary long script or another program - [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32544673/5994041)

Comment: You're right, KeyWeeUsr, on the URL "http://www.windows-commandline.com/find-windows-os-version-from-command/" I've found some interesting information.

Comment: Just type `ver`. For example, on my Windows 7 system I get "Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]" which tells me that I am running Windows 7 (which has [version number 6.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions)).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

#### Is there a command to determine if I'm working on a Windows 10 system?

You can use `wmic`.

The following command will return the Windows version.

```
wmic os get Caption | findstr /v Caption
```

Example output:

```
F:\test>wmic os get Caption | findstr /v Caption
Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium
```

If you want a little more information, you can use the following batch file (GetOS.cmd), which will retrieve and display:

- Operating System Version
- Service Pack Major Version
- Architecture (64 or 32 bit)

```bsh
@echo off
setlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set _os=
set _sp=
rem use findstr to strip blank lines from wmic output
rem get OS
for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=3" %%i in (`wmic os get caption ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do (
  set "_os=%%i"
  )
rem get Service Pack
for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=*" %%i in (`wmic os get ServicePackMajorVersion ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do (
  set "_sp=%%i"
  )
rem get Architecture
for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=*" %%i in (`wmic OS get OSArchitecture ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do (
  set "_bits=%%i"
  )
echo Operating System Version: %_os%
echo Service Pack Major Version: %_sp%
echo Architecture: %_bits%
endlocal
```

The OS Version is stored in `%_os`, Service Pack Major Version is stored in `%_sp%`, and the Architecture is stored in `%_bits%`.

Notes:

- Not completely tested as I don't have all the OS and Service Pack combinations to test it with.
- The `for` command retrieves only the 3rd part (token) of the OS. This will work for the desktop versions (if you want to distinguish Server 2008 from other versions you will need to find another solution).
- `%_os` will be set to one of the following values: `Server`, `Vista`, `7`, `8`, `8.1` or `10`.

Example output:

```
F:\test>GetOS
Operating System Version: 7
Service Pack Major Version: 1
Architecture: 64-bit

F:\test>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows command line related.
- [Findstr - Search for strings - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [For /f- Loop through command output - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [If - Conditionally perform command - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [WMIC - Windows Management - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html)

Answer (score 34):

I can't believe this long and no ver command

```
C:\>ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]

C:\>
```

It works in redirects so you can do

```
ver | find "Version 10."
```

But you should normally write "for this and all future versions" so you're better off enumerating through the previous ones.

Comment: FYI `ver` does *not* work in PowerShell.  It is `CMD` specific.

Comment: @Keltari But `iex "ver"` does!

Comment: The output of `ver` can be a bit misleading. On the machine I am sitting at right now it returns `Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]`. But i am quite certain it runs Windows 7, not Windows 6.

Comment: @Philipp Yes, Windows 7 and 8 are "really" patch releases of Vista, 6.1 and 6.2 respectively; the major version bump is strictly marketing. I do not know whether the changes in Windows 10 are significant enough to warrant a major version bump. (From the hardline software engineering perspective, the major version of any software should only ever be bumped to indicate a backward compatibility break; it follows that large major versions are *bad*. Unfortunately, the marketing department likes large numbers.)

Comment: @Philipp - its easy to find a map from version number to marketing names, e.g., [here](http://prajwaldesai.com/windows-operating-system-version-numbers/)

Comment: Windows 7 and 8/8.1 used 6.1/6.2/6.3 because vista had such a significantly changed driver architecture from XP that they coded it to only work if the system reported Windows major version as 6. In Windows 10 microsoft felt that drivers have advanced far enough since then to change the number again. The biggest offenders if I recall were graphics vendors. I wouldn't call them "patches" of vista, even though they closely follow its driver model.

Comment: Nice to know about this command. It's unclear what you mean in the first line, though.

Comment: The question was 7 hours old and the answer should be stupid obvious to anybody whose been around awhile.

Comment: In fact the numbering is the "NT" version, not strictly the Windows version.

Answer (score 18):

> systeminfo

gets many usefull infos like Operating system, System type (32/64 bit) and so long:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I would recommend `systeminfo` also.  As you can see from the image above, it will display your operating system as well as other information you may need.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. `systeminfo` indeed gives the information I'm looking for (hence the upvote), but it takes quite some time (on my PC it takes more than 15 seconds). Therefore I've opted for the `wmic` solution, found in the next answer.

Comment: This is what I ask people to run when I need to find out os/version they are running on: `cmd /c systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version"`

Comment: systeminfo's output is language dependent, so quite useless if you want ot run it on a larger scale

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience with InstallAnywhere but there are two options to see what OS is installed using a command-line.

1. Using Cmd

   ```
   systeminfo.exe
   ```

   Using the command `systeminfo.exe`, you can see result of under the field `OS Name`. This may give you more information than you require.

   More information on this command can be found in [Microsoft TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb491007.aspx).
2. Powershell

   Alternatively you could use the following Powershell script which will return the exact information you want.

   ```
   Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object  Caption | ForEach{ $_.Caption }
   ```